# HTML 5 2D Canvas Animation Clearing

Tags: html, canvas, 2d, automatic-ref-counting

I've been following various guides and have the base code up for a simple animation but for the life of me I cannot get the canvas to reset correctly. The clearRect() function is working perfectly but when I try to draw an arc again immediatly afterwards it draws the sum of all the paths again rather than just drawing the single segment of the circle.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here, I know it's a simple solution! In short I would like the test page below to produce a kind of spinning segment instead of just drawing a circle:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

</head>
<body>
<span id="degrees_output" style="display:block;width:60px"></span>
<button onclick="continue_animation=false;">Stop</button>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
  var degrees = 0;
  var continue_animation = true;
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var output = document.getElementById('degrees_output');      

  window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
  })();

  function animate() {        
    // update
    output.innerHTML = degrees;

    var radians = (degrees / 180) * Math.PI;

    if (degrees >= 360)
        degrees = 0;
    else
        degrees += 1;

    // clear
    if (degrees % 20 == 0)
    {           
        context.clearRect(0, 0, 578, 200);

    }

    context.beginPath();

    // setup the line style     
    context.strokeStyle = '#fa00ff';
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.lineCap = 'round';


    context.arc(50, 50, 20, 0, radians, false);

    // colour the path
    context.stroke();

    context.closePath();                


    // request new frame
    requestAnimFrame(function() {
        if (continue_animation)
            animate();
    });
  }
  animate();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a fixed length arc to sweep around your circle, you'll want to specify both the starting and ending angles in your context.arc like this:

```
context.arc(50, 50, 20, startRadians, radians, false);
```

and startRadians can just be any angle behind your "radians" value:

```
var startRadians= (degrees-45) * Math.PI/180;
```

and, Yes, you will need to clear the canvas (at least the previous arc) before drawing the arc in a new position:

```
context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/VFhzX/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var degrees = 0;
    var continue_animation = true;
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var output = document.getElementById('degrees_output');      

    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
      return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };
    })();

    function animate() {        
      // update
      output.innerHTML = degrees;

      var radians = (degrees / 180) * Math.PI;
      var startRadians= (degrees-45) * Math.PI/180;

      if (degrees >= 360)
          degrees = 0;
      else
          degrees += 1;

      // clear
      if (degrees % 20 == 0)
      {           
          context.clearRect(0, 0, 578, 200);

      }

      context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

      context.beginPath();

      // setup the line style     
      context.strokeStyle = '#fa00ff';
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.lineCap = 'round';


      context.arc(50, 50, 20, startRadians, radians, false);

      // colour the path
      context.stroke();

      context.closePath();                


      // request new frame
      requestAnimFrame(function() {
          if (continue_animation)
              animate();
      });
    }
    animate();



}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <span id="degrees_output" style="display:block;width:60px"></span>
    <button onclick="continue_animation=false;">Stop</button>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```